# Loop Through Each HTML Table Column and Get the Data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, foreach

i'm trying to get the data inside the html `<tbody>`. Basically, i have many rows like this;
[image]

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>Computer</td>
                        <td>3434</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="mprDetailRemove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>64</td>
                        <td>Stationary</td>
                        <td>111</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="Button1"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>64</td>
                        <td>Stationary</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn-medium btn-danger remove" id="Button2"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Now, i'm looping through and trying to get the `<td>` values like this;

```
        var table = $("#mprDetailDataTable table tbody");

        table.find('tr').each(function (key, val) {
            $(this).find('td').each(function (key, val) {
                var productId = val[key].innerHTML; // this isn't working
                var product = ?
                var Quantity = ?
            });
        });
```

But, i'm not able to get the values(html text) of the each row. **I want to assign these values to local variables.** 
**Also, i don't want to get the `innerHTML` of a button (which is in each row)**

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Using a nested `.each()` means that your inner loop is doing one td at a time, so you can't set the `productId` and `product` and `quantity` all in the inner loop.

Also using `function(key, val)` and then `val[key].innerHTML` isn't right: the [`.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) passes the index (an integer) and the actual element, so you'd use `function(i, element)` and then `element.innerHTML`. Though jQuery also sets `this` to the element, so you can just say `this.innerHTML`.

Anyway, here's a way to get it to work:

```
    table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            productId = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
            Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();
        // do something with productId, product, Quantity
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bqX7Q/

Comment: I had a similar need, and made this jsfiddle based on this answer:  https://jsfiddle.net/kershaw/o3bh6kxc/30/

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
    $("#mprDetailDataTable tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
        var this_row = $(this);
        var productId = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(0)').html());//td:eq(0) means first td of this row
        var product = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(1)').html())
        var Quantity = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(2)').html())
    });
```

Comment: does it work only with html() function? i try to use other functions on the records such as val() and attr() but nothing works. what is the problem precisely?

Answer (score 4):

My first post...

I tried this: change 'tr' for 'td' and you will get all HTMLRowElements into an Array, and using textContent will change from Object into String

```
var dataArray = [];
var data = table.find('td'); //Get All HTML td elements

// Save important data into new Array
for (var i = 0; i <= data.size() - 1; i = i + 4)
{
  dataArray.push(data[i].textContent, data[i + 1].textContent, data[i + 2].textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your table, put your td with class = "suma"

```
$(function(){   

   //funcion suma todo

   var sum = 0;
   $('.suma').each(function(x,y){
       sum += parseInt($(this).text());                                   
   })           
   $('#lblTotal').text(sum);   

   // funcion suma por check                                           

    $( "input:checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){     
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last').addClass('suma2');
   }else{       
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:last').removeClass('suma2');
   }    
   suma2Total();                                                           
   })                                                      

   function suma2Total(){
      var sum2 = 0;
      $('.suma2').each(function(x,y){
        sum2 += parseInt($(this).text());       
      })
      $('#lblTotal2').text(sum2);                                              
   }                                                                      
});
```

[Ejemplo completo](https://jsfiddle.net/madaver1980/hncna0j5/)

Comment: To keep the site clean, try to avoid shorthand like 'ur' instead of 'your, 'u', instead of 'you', etc. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with textContent.

```
var productId = val[key].textContent;
```