# Iterate through a single column of HTML table efficiently and properly

Tags: javascript

You may want to look for the **check()** function [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/175/)

```
function check(){
   var i = 0;
   var s = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < tbody.rows.length; i++){
     if(tbody.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].textContent == "unit_3"){
        s = i;
     }
   }
return s ;
}
```

I did this function to iterate through a specific column of my table. I was wondering since I don't know much about Javascript and iterations if there is a *better & faster* way to look for a specific value in a column because in a real case I may have actually a lot of rows so I want the iteration to be fast. I suck with jQuery but any suggestion is welcome :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop Through Each HTML Table Column and Get the Data using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120633/loop-through-each-html-table-column-and-get-the-data-using-jquery)

Comment: It's not  for each column but just for one column actually

Comment: A first step would be to break the loop when the value is found, by doing `return i;` instead of `s = i;`, and return false or -1 at the end if the value is not found.

Comment: How do you define "efficiently", "properly", "better", and "faster"?

Comment: jQuery does this very easily: x = $('tr:contains("unit_3")').index();

Comment: I've noticed in certain cases that `while` loops perform faster than `for` loops : [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/179/).

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I'll try them all

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 6 introduces [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (which can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill)):

```js
function check() {
    return [].findIndex.call(tbody.rows, function(row) {
        return row.cells[0].textContent == "unit_3";
    });
}
```