# Creating charts using chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I need to create charts using chart.js , however I have created a basic one using the chart.js documentation. But now I want the data source to be HTML Table instead of Array object.

## Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <script src="chart.js"></script>
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");

    var data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      }, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
      }]
    };
    var MyNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
  </script>

  <table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jane</th>

            <th>Jordan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Apples</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Pears</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Plums</th>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Bananas</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Oranges</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Carret</th>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

===================

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

This question [Looping through table data with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120633/loop-through-each-html-table-column-and-get-the-data-using-jquery) has answers that discuss how to pull data from a table using jquery. Ideally if your table is be being generated from server side you could pass that data set into a JSON data set to be used on the page by both chart and table.

Comment: this should be a comment