# How to only display 'Edit' link on certain rows on apex interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report apex5.0 which contains several fields.
Would like to disable 'edit' pencil option link where payment_date & code is populated.
Link is to be enabled only where `payment_date` & code is null.
Disable the edit button for a particular row, based on a specific value in its column.

For ex. If a grid has 3 columns A,B,C and if B contains "Apple", and '01-jan-17', the edit button for that row must be disabled.

What are the different options to do this kind of functionality in apex5.0, enable & disable "EDIT" based on certain criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use JavaScript on page load:
Let's asume that first column is with ID and used to show edit link. Second column is your product name like Apple. Just disable click on this element(cell with ID) or change link, img etc.

```
var table = $(".a-IRR-table tbody");
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        productId = $tds.eq(0).text(), //first column with ID and edit link
        product = $tds.eq(1).text(),   //second column
        Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();  //third column
if (product == 'Apple'){
    $tds.eq(0).click(false);
    $tds.eq(0).replaceWith('');
}
    
});
```

Thanks to this answer for JavaScript:  [Loop Through Each HTML Table Column and Get the Data using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120633/loop-through-each-html-table-column-and-get-the-data-using-jquery)

**EDIT:**
To hide value based on your Query use CASE. For example:

```
SELECT
 CASE
  WHEN B = 'Apple' THEN
    '<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#edit.gif" alt="">'
  ELSE ''
END edit_link,
A,B,C
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Click on column edit_link and make it of type Link

Choose your target to edit page

For link text select #EDIT_LINK#

Escape special characters must be set to NO

On Report Atributes set **Link Column** to **Exclude Link Column** (you have custom link column so don't display original link)

*Check your online workspace, page 3*

Comment: i got an online workspace.. will u be able to help on that?

Comment: Sure, I can try :)

Comment: can you please check ..... workspace: AKIKA  user Name : akika1508@gmail.com  password:esting123
refer to Application : 12345678     https://apex.oracle.com/en/

Comment: Sorry, it says Invalid Login Credentials

Comment: sorry password is testing123

Comment: check page 55 I make quick demo

Comment: hi, is there a way to hide it when $tds.eq(0).click(false); and make it visible only when condition is not met .ie (product !== 'Apple')

Comment: check page 55 :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also add a case statement to your report's query.

E.g.

```
(Case when [some logic] then
  --display link
 '<a href="f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':47:' || :APP_SESSION || '::NO:47:P47_ID:'|| a.id || '" title="Edit"><img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#menu/pencil16x16.gif" alt="" /></a>'
  End) as col_link
```

The above example will only display a link if the case statement is met. The link will point to page 47 and we will pass the query's Id column to page 47's item P47_ID

In order to treat this new column as a link you must change the "display as text" property to "standard report column"; you can achieve this when editing the report attributes.